# Trying to get path into variable; permission denied

Tags: bash, variable, wildcards

I have 20 files of interest in a directory. They can be split into 5 groups, each group identified by a number from 626 to 630 in the file name.
For example, there might (hypothetically) be a file named
`the-quick-brown-fox-jumps-over-627-lazy-dogs_1_bbduk.fq`.

I would like to iterate through each group and temporarily store the paths to the files as text variables
(to be used with other commands within the `for` loop). 
This is what I have for now:

```
for i in {626..630};do
  fw1=$(/scratch/[username]/data/*"$i"-*_1_bbduk.fq)
  fw2=$(/scratch/[username]/data/*"$i"_*_1_bbduk.fq)
  rv1=$(/scratch/[username]/data/*"$i"-*_2_bbduk.fq)
  rv2=$(/scratch/[username]/data/*"$i"_*_2_bbduk.fq)
done
```

Issue: I get the correct path (there is only one option for each of them), but it says "Permission denied", and I seem unable to use the variable as text later on. It looks like bash is trying to execute it, which is not what I want.

I've tried adding single quotes around (e.g., `fw1='$(/scratch/[username]/data/*"$i"-*_1_bbduk.fq)'`, but that removes the wildcards. I've considered double quotes ( " " ), but I'm not sure how to use them without messing with the "$i" variable. I've tried using `echo` (e.g., `fw1=echo $(/scratch/[username]/data/*"$i"-*_1_bbduk.fq)` but that still has the 'permission denied' issue.

Comment: Since you already have the path, which path are you trying to get into each var? Are you refering to the whole filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jim correctly identified](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/696277/80216) the problem with your code,
but (IMO) a better solution is closer to what you already have:

```
fw1=(/scratch/username/data/*"$i"-*_1_bbduk.fq)
```

(note: no **`$`**) will give you an array of filenames that match the glob. 
The somewhat awkward `${#fw1[@]}` will tell you
how many elements are in the array. 
If, for example, that number is `4`, then you can use
`${fw1[0]}`, `${fw1[1]}`, `${fw1[2]}` and `${fw1[3]}` to access
the four elements. 
But plain `$fw1` will give you `${fw1[0]}`, so, if you’re 110% sure
that there will be exactly one file matching each pattern,
you can just use the short form.

***Or**,* you could say

```
fw1=$(echo /scratch/username/data/*"$i"-*_1_bbduk.fq)
```

Again, you were close. 
(But the array solution is better if there’s any possibility
that there will be more than one file matching the pattern.)

Answer (score 4):

Bash is trying to execute the filename because you enclose each one in

```
$( ... )
```

If that is not what you want, then use:

```
for i in {626..630}; do
  fw1=/scratch/[username]/data/*"$i"-*_1_bbduk.fq
  fw2=/scratch/[username]/data/*"$i"_*_1_bbduk.fq
  rv1=/scratch/[username]/data/*"$i"-*_2_bbduk.fq
  rv2=/scratch/[username]/data/*"$i"_*_2_bbduk.fq
done
```

**Edit:**

Based on your comment, this code may be what you want:

```
for i in {626..630}; do
  fw1="$(compgen -G /scratch/[username]/data/*"$i"-*_1_bbduk.fq)"
  fw2="$(compgen -G /scratch/[username]/data/*"$i"_*_1_bbduk.fq)"
  rv1="$(compgen -G /scratch/[username]/data/*"$i"-*_2_bbduk.fq)"
  rv2="$(compgen -G /scratch/[username]/data/*"$i"_*_2_bbduk.fq)"
done
```

Comment: Thank you! It's not quite sufficient because this command seems to remove with the wildcards. For example, adding 'echo "$fw1"  ' afterwards as a test gives out stuff like '/scratch/[username]/data/*626-*_1_bbduk.fq', as opposed to, for example, '/scratch/[username]/data/File0626-sequence_1_bbduk.fq'. The wildcards are slightly different for different files so I can't easily account for them.